# IOS - After search/filter, how to select rowAtIndexPath

Tags: core-data, ios6, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a splitView app, where I have installed search/filtering.

The filtering works for the master view, but I cannot figure out how to set "didSelectRowAtIndexPath". It seems that the link between Root and Detail is lost.

I tried to reconnect using this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

     if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
     {
         self.selectedItem = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath];
     }
     else
     {
         self.selectedItem = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     }

    detailViewController.item = self.selectedItem;
    [self.detailViewController.tableView reloadData];
```

But that doesn't gives me an NSRangeException.

If instead, I use:

```
self.selectedItem = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

no exception, but the detail view is not captured.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Why do you call `indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];` instead of using the `indexPath` supplied as parameter to the function?

Comment: Brilliant. that was it.. Thanks so much. If you could suggest this as the answer, I will accept right away.. Sometimes, a second pair of eyes is all that's needed. Thank you again..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary (and probably wrong) to call

```
indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

because the selected row is supplied as parameter to `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.